# Deleting pdf files after merge

Tags: pdf, unlink

I merge two pdf files as one pdf by using the pdfMerger class.
After the merging has completed, I want to delete the old pdf files.

This is my code.
Please help me.

```
include 'PDFMerger.php';
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', 'all');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', 'all');     
$pdf->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');

$files = glob('path/*');    
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
if(is_file($file))
unlink($file); // delete file
}

$pdf->Output('samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: It seems you showed us the code of how you merge the files but do you also have some code of what you did in order to delete the 2 other files? for me it seems you just need to look for the command which is deleting files and that's it.

Comment: Yes , thats the actual code am using for unlink the pdf files, But that code was not working after merging was done..

Comment: And id i use that unlink code at the top of merge line it will work fine but merging was not done. If i use below the merge line it will not working

Comment: you should comment on the answer I've written and not here in the question. Try doing it after the output command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to delete a file taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('test.html', 'a');
fwrite($fh, '<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
fclose($fh);

unlink('test.html');
?>
```

In this example you can see they use the test.html file and in the end, the unlink command is deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not use the PDFMerger class, because it uses an outdated version of FPDI from 2009!!

Switch to a native current version with [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/) and delete the files AFTER the call of Output(). Deleting a file before calling Output() will result in errors, because there are file handles opened and the files are still used by methods which are called internally in the Output() method.